# ConstraintLayout View size - ratio with parent

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I'm learning how to use `ConstraintLayout`. I want to make menu with 4 element.

- Elements should be centered in parent
- Elements should be size 1:5 of parent height (ratio 1:1 - square)

I have made something like this:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/split"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/tiles_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/split"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/container_v"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/container_h"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tile_1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/tile_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tile_size"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/tile_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/tile_margin"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/container_v"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/container_h"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tile_2"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/tile_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tile_size"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/tile_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/tile_margin"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/container_v"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/container_h"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tile_3"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/tile_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tile_size"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tile_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/tile_margin"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/container_h"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/container_v"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tile_4"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/tile_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tile_size"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tile_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/tile_margin"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/container_h"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/container_v"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Unfortunately, I had to hardcode Images width and height. Is it possible to set size of child based on ratio with parent (like in Xcode)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should never nest a ConstraintLayout inside another one. You should always maintain a flat layout hierarchy.

The "1.1.0-beta3" release of ConstraintLayout allows the usage of percentage dimensions and many more cool features.

Just set the "layout_constraintHeight_default" attribute to "percent" (to use percentage units), and set the percentage using "layout_constraintHeight_percent". (width related attributes are available too)

Here's the solution using Guidelines:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#caf">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_ver"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".5" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_hor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".5" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/topLeft"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_hor"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline_ver" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/topRight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_hor"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guideline_ver" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomLeft"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline_ver"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline_hor" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomRight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guideline_ver"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline_hor" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Layout capture]

Hope this helps!

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3'

Comment: "You should never nest a ConstraintLayout inside another one"  Could you explain why you should not do this? Or show documentation on why?  I don't see how you could create more complex views without doing so.

Comment: Mobile devices refresh their display at 60 fps, so your app has 16 ms to update each frame. if a frame rendering exceeds that limit, it will be dropped and you will see LAG. Nested layouts takes more time to render than flat ones which is why they are bad for performance. It's even worse if you nest a RelativeLayout or a LinearLayout that uses weight because these two call onMesure twice each time they are rendered. So, it's much faster if we have a flat layout hierarchy.

Comment: IMHO, it is true that you cannot avoid nesting layouts using the 1.0.2 stable release of constraint layout. But I have been using the 1.1.0 beta release long enough to know that a flat layout hierarchy no matter how complex the design is can be achieved. This release has some great new features like barriers, groups, circular positioning, percent dimensions and placeholders. Check it out.